# PHP-SOAP extension is not loaded

Tags: php, php-extension

I have Centos 6.4 Final running on a (Linux certified) HP PC.   I'm writing a small EPOS app in PHP and need to access various Magento SOAP methods.

When I installed php (via yum) I did not know I needed SOAP.  So i used yum install php-soap at a later date.    After which I did yum update.

Looking at the phpinfo() output
Link http://www.prendas.co.uk/images/download/phpinfo.pdf

SOAP appears to be working.    However I get "SOAP extension is not loaded." in my PHP code when I try and load it.

Can anybody pls help?

Comment: please post the code where you are loading it in PHP.

Comment: the message you've quoted is not coming from PHP itself, so it must be in your code. Find out where that message is being generated, and what conditions it is testing. That might give you more clues.

Comment: It would be helpful to us to post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Php.ini**   File from phpmyadmin open in text editor and search for **;extension=php_soap.dll** and just remove **;** symbol and after that **restart** your Wamp/xamp services and then **refresh** your url page..enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know much about centOS, but it could be possible, that there are two php.ini files. One for Apache and one for the CLI. So in case you place your SOAP-call from CLI (which I thought to be likely), you might have to add the SOAP-extension to the list of loaded extensions within this CLI's php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

ok just go to `php.ini` file and see if `extension=php_soap.dll` actually exist, if it doesn't, then look through the file and find where your extensions are and paste extension=php_soap.dll. if `extension=php_soap.dll` actually exist but it's written as `;extension=php_soap.dll` then remove the semi-colon, save the file, stop and restart your modules and voila!!!